# document.write asynchronous (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I've got some tracking code that I have to embed in the footer of my page.  The tracking code is from a 3rd party company and uses `document.write` which of course is blocking.  I've sent a support request to the company and they don't seem to have any interest in changing the code.

The tracking code looks something like this:

```
document.write (
  '<img src="http://company-url.com/visitor.gif?ts='+
  new Date().getTime()+
  '&ref='+escape(document.referrer) + '">'
);
```

So, my question is, is it possible to make `document.write` non blocking?

Comment: What do you mean it is blocking? Can you not just rewrite it to be `document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '<img ... />'`?

Comment: I wouldn't use `document.write` at *all* if I had the choice!

Comment: So you know, it's not `document.write` that's blocking, but rather all script execution is blocking, unless you use stuff like `defer` or `async`. But then `document.write` doesn't work any longer.

Comment: Is this third-party code an inline script or one with an external `src`? If the latter, there's not much you can do, but if it's inline so you can change it, @bfavaretto's solution would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to make `document.write` asynchronous. But you can just append an img to the body after page load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var url = 'http://company-url.com/visitor.gif?ts='+new Date().getTime()+'&ref='+escape(document.referrer);
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```